# Execute "sp_msforeachdb" in a Java application

Tags: java, sql-server, stored-procedures, jdbc, sp-msforeachdb

Hi StackOverflow community :)

I come to you to share one of my problems...

I have to extract a **list of every table in each database of a SQL Server instance**, I found this query :

```
EXEC sp_msforeachdb 'Use ?; SELECT DB_NAME() AS DB, * FROM sys.tables'
```

It works perfectly on Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio but when I try to execute it **in my Java program** (that includes JDBC drivers for SQL Server) it says that it **doesn't return any result**.

My Java code is the following :

```
this.statement = this.connect.createStatement(); // Create the statement
this.resultats = this.statement.executeQuery("EXEC sp_msforeachdb 'Use ?; SELECT DB_NAME() AS DB, * FROM sys.tables'"); // Execute the query and store results in a ResultSet

this.sortie.ecrireResultats(this.statement.getResultSet()); // Write the ResultSet to a file
```

Thanks to anybody who will try to help me,
***Have a nice day :)***

**EDIT 1 :**

I'm not sure that the JDBC driver for SQL Server supports my query so I'll try to get to my goal in another way.

What I'm trying to get is a **list of all the tables for each database on a SQL Server instance**, the output format will be the following :

```
+-----------+--------+
| Databases | Tables |
+-----------+--------+
```

So now I'm asking can someone help me to get to that solution **using SQL queries thru Java's JDBC for SQL Server driver**.

I also wish to thanks the very quick answers I got from [Tim Lehner](https://stackoverflow.com/users/880904/tim-lehner) and [Mark Rotteveel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/466862/mark-rotteveel).

Answer (score 4):

If a statement can return no or **multiple** results, you should not use `executeQuery`, but [`execute()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#executeQuery(java.lang.String)) instead, this method returns a `boolean` indicating the type of the first result:

- `true`: result is a `ResultSet`
- `false` : result is an update count

If the result is `true`, then you use [`getResultSet()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#getResultSet%28%29) to retrieve the `ResultSet`, otherwise [`getUpdateCount()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#getUpdateCount%28%29) to retrieve the update count. If the update count is `-1` it means there are no more results. Note that the update count will also be `-1` when the current result is a `ResultSet`. It is also good to know that `getResultSet()` should return null if there are no more results or if the result is an update count.

Now if you want to retrieve more results, you call [`getMoreResults()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#getMoreResults%28%29) (or its brother accepting an `int` parameter). The return value of `boolean` has the same meaning as that of `execute()`, so `false` does not mean there are no more results!

There are only no more results if the `getMoreResults()` returns false and `getUpdateCount()` returns `-1` (as also documented in the Javadoc)

Essentially this means that if you want to correctly process all results you need to do something like below:

```
boolean result = stmt.execute(...);
while(true)
    if (result) {
        ResultSet rs = stmt.getResultSet();
        // Do something with resultset ...
    } else {
        int updateCount = stmt.getUpdateCount();
        if (updateCount == -1) {
            // no more results
            break;
        }
        // Do something with update count ...
    }
    result = stmt.getMoreResults();
}
```

NOTE: Part of this answer is based on my answer to [Java SQL: Statement.hasResultSet()?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14413141/466862)

Comment: Your post is very complete and taught me a lot about some methods is still don't master. The problem is that I implemented your solution and I can't get it to work with my query... I don't think it's supported by the driver.

Comment: @VincentKelleher That is unfortunate, I will see if I can find an alternative solution.

Comment: Thank you very much ! I spent days searching everywhere and nobody ever tried seemingly...

Answer (score 1):

If you're not getting an error, one issue might be that `sp_msforeachdb` will return a separate result set for each database rather than one set with all records.  That being the case, you might try a bit of dynamic SQL to union-up all of your rows:

```
-- Use sys.tables
declare @sql nvarchar(max)
select @sql = coalesce(@sql + ' union all ', '') + 'select ''' + quotename(name) + ''' as database_name, * from ' + quotename(name) + '.sys.tables'
from sys.databases
select @sql = @sql + ' order by database_name, name'
exec sp_executesql @sql
```

I still sometimes use INFORMATION_SCHEMA views as well, since it's easier to see the schema name, among other things:

```
-- Use INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES to easily get schema name
declare @sql nvarchar(max)
select @sql = coalesce(@sql + ' union all ', '') + 'select * from ' + quotename(name) + '.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES where TABLE_TYPE = ''BASE TABLE'''
from sys.databases
select @sql = @sql + ' order by TABLE_CATALOG, TABLE_SCHEMA, TABLE_NAME'
exec sp_executesql @sql
```

Be aware that this method of string concatenation (`select @sql = foo from bar`) [may not work as you intend through a linked server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13019624/why-do-i-get-these-different-results-from-two-sql-queries) (it will only grab the last record).  Just a small caveat.

Comment: Wow fast answer !
Can I include that into my Java program ?

Comment: I'm not overly familiar with JDBC, so I'm merely guessing that you can put this whole thing in your `executeQuery()` command.  If that's not working, you might try a basic `exec sp_who` or something just to make sure you can get a resultset from a proc this way. Logging into SSMS with the same user/pass as your app can't hurt either.

Comment: I'll try that tomorrow and will keep you informed on my progression. Anyway, thank you for your help !

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE**

**I've found the solution !**

After reading [an article about sp_spaceused being used with Java](http://bryanpendleton.blogspot.fr/2009/05/spspaceused-and-multiple-jdbc-result.html), I figured out that I was in the same case.

My final code is the following :

```
this.instances = instances;
for(int i = 0 ; i < this.instances.size() ; i++)
{
    try
    {
        Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
        this.connect = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlserver://" + this.instances.get(i), "tluser", "result");

        this.statement = this.connect.prepareCall("{call sp_msforeachdb(?)}");
        this.statement.setString(1, "Use ?; SELECT DB_NAME() AS DB, name FROM sys.tables WHERE DB_NAME() NOT IN('master', 'model', 'msdb', 'tempdb')");
        this.resultats = this.statement.execute();

        while(true)
        {
            int rowCount = this.statement.getUpdateCount();
            if(rowCount > 0)
            {
                this.statement.getMoreResults();
                continue;
            }
            if(rowCount == 0)
            {
                this.statement.getMoreResults();
                continue;
            }

            ResultSet rs = this.statement.getResultSet();
            if(rs != null)
            {
                while (rs.next())
                {
                     this.sortie.ecrireResultats(rs); // Write the results to a file
                }
                rs.close();
                this.statement.getMoreResults();
                continue;
            }
            break;
        }
        this.statement.close();
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

It tried it out and my file has everything I want in it.

***Thank you all for your help ! :)***