# Null resultsets when calling Sybase stored procedure through JDBC

Tags: java, jdbc, sybase

I'm calling a Sybase stored procedure that returns multiple resultsets through JDBC.
I need to get a specific result set that has a column named "Result"
This is my code :

```
CallableStatement cs = conn.prepareCall(sqlCall);
cs.registerOutParameter(1, Types.VARCHAR);
cs.execute();
ResultSet rs=null;
int count = 1;
boolean flag = true;
while (count < 20000 && flag == true) {
    cs.getMoreResults();
    rs = cs.getResultSet();
    if (rs != null) {
        ResultSetMetaData resultSetMetaData = rs.getMetaData();
        int columnsCount = resultSetMetaData.getColumnCount();
        if (resultSetMetaData.getColumnName(1).equals("Result")) {
            // action code resultset found 
            flag = false;
            // loop on the resultset and add the elements returned to an array list
            while (rs.next()) {
                int x = 1;
                while (x <= columnsCount) {
                   result.add(rs.getString(x));
                   x++;
                }
            }
            result.add(0, cs.getString(1));
        }
    }
    count++;
}
```

What happens here is that `cs.getMoreResults` returns a lot of null resultsets till it reaches the target one. I can't use `cs.getMoreResults` as loop condition because it returns false for null resultsets.

I put a fixed number to end the loop in condition the wanted result set wasn't returned to prevent it from going into infinite loop. It worked fine but I don't think this is right.

I think the null resultsets returned from the assignment in Sybase `select @variable = value`

Has anyone faced this before?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are misinterpreting the return value of `getMoreResults()`. You are also ignoring the return value of [`execute()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#executeQuery(java.lang.String)), this method returns a `boolean` indicating the type of the first result:

- `true`: result is a `ResultSet`
- `false` : result is an update count

If the result is `true`, then you use [`getResultSet()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#getResultSet%28%29) to retrieve the `ResultSet`, otherwise [`getUpdateCount()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#getUpdateCount%28%29) to retrieve the update count. If the update count is `-1` it means there are no more results. Note that the update count will also be `-1` when the current result is a `ResultSet`. It is also good to know that `getResultSet()` should return null if there are no more results or if the result is an update count (this last condition is why you get so many `null` values).

Now if you want to retrieve more results, you call [`getMoreResults()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#getMoreResults%28%29) (or its brother accepting an `int` parameter). The return value of `boolean` has the same meaning as that of `execute()`, so `false` *does not mean there are no more results*!

There are only no more results if the `getMoreResults()` returns false and `getUpdateCount()` returns `-1` (as also documented in the Javadoc)

Essentially this means that if you want to correctly process all results you need to do something like below:

```
boolean result = stmt.execute(...);
while(true) {
    if (result) {
        ResultSet rs = stmt.getResultSet();
        // Do something with resultset ...
    } else {
        int updateCount = stmt.getUpdateCount();
        if (updateCount == -1) {
            // no more results
            break;
        }
        // Do something with update count ...
    }
    result = stmt.getMoreResults();
}
```

My guess is that you are getting a lot of update counts before you get the actual `ResultSet`.

I am not really familiar with Sybase, but its cousin SQL Server has the 'annoying' feature to return update counts from stored procedures if you don't explicitly put `SET NOCOUNT ON;` at the start of the stored procedure.

NOTE: Part of this answer is based on my answer to [Execute “sp_msforeachdb” in a Java application](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14694174/466862)

Comment: I ran into this same issue with Sql Server and you're answer helped me solve it. I could not figure out why `stmt.execute()` with some data would return `false` even though I could clearly see data in the result sets returned when running it manually. I'm still not sure I understand the `updateCount()` since I don't believe the stored proc is actually updating any data..

Comment: @Catfish You could als try adding `SET NOCOUNT ON` in your sp.

Comment: I don't have access to modify the stored proc. You're answer seems to work in my case. Thanks.