# java.sql.PreparedStatement.execute() returns false sometimes even if there are results

Tags: java, sql, sql-server, jdbc, prepared-statement

I'm working with a SQL Server stored procedure by calling it in my Java app and writing the results to a spreadsheet.

I noticed that there some rows in my spreadsheet with no data.

When i was debugging my app, I noticed that this line:

```
boolean hasResults = stmt.execute();
```

is returning false on the rows that are missing in my spreadsheet. If i run the stored procedure manually, it returns results for the same input data that it's failing on in my Java code.

How can this return false if it returns data when I run the stored procedure manually in SQuirreL SQL?

Comment: The stored proc produces 3 result sets. In this case, the first 2 contain at least 1 record.

Comment: It works for almost 500 rows. Fails on about 10 of them.

Comment: I found how to get all of the results from this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14829130/null-resultsets-when-calling-sybase-stored-procedure-through-jdbc