# JDBC callable statement returns null resultset , if temp tabel is used in SP

Tags: java, sql-server, jdbc, callable-statement

Here, is simple e.g. of How I'm using callablestatement

```
Connection con = getConnection();
CallableStatement call = con.prepareCall("{call SpName(?, ?)}");
call .setObject(1, params[0]);
call .setObject(2, params[1]);
call .execute();
ResultSet rs = call .getResultSet();
```

It's working fine for all SP.
But if there is temp table used in SP then it returns null Resultset.

Comment: Show us your stored procedure and then perhaps we'll be able to help you.

Comment: You are not checking the result of `execute`, its boolean return value shows if the first result is an update count or a result set. And if you didn't use `set nocount on` in your stored procedure, then the first result(s) will be an update count. See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14829130/null-resultsets-when-calling-sybase-stored-procedure-through-jdbc and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14690295/execute-sp-msforeachdb-in-a-java-application

Comment: @MarkRotteveel : thanks you are right i found same answer from some other link which i have mentioned in answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved my problem by adding this code

```
while (true) {
    rs = cstmt.getResultSet();
    int updateCount = cstmt.getUpdateCount();
    LogWriter.write(" Update count " + updateCount);
    if (rs == null && updateCount == -1) {
        break;
    }
    if (rs != null) {
        // process the result set
    } else {
        System.out.println("Update count = " + cstmt.getUpdateCount());
    }
    cstmt.getMoreResults();
}
```

Reference: [Here](http://coderanch.com/t/300855/JDBC/databases/JDBC-Callable-Statement-JConnect-Returning)